# Can I dedicate a patent to someone?

Tags: assignment

What are the ways or steps via which I can dedicate my patent to someone else as an innovator? I have tried searching on the USPTO and it only tells about transferring the ownership. Another way I can think of is adding that person as the co-inventor but still this is not something considered as gifting the patent.

Comment: Do you want to acknowledge them or gift the patent ?

Answer (score 1):

Only actual inventors can be listed as an inventor on a patent. Listing a false inventor could potentially lead to invalidation of the patent. Although this is unlikely, I would avoid this.

Unlike technical papers, it is not a thing to offer a dedication in a patent. In fact I’ve never seen it done. You could try just writing one in the the body of the patent, but the patent examiner may not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very unconventional but you could probably thank a mentor in a sentence without messing anything up.